# Remove pairs of nested brackets anywhere in a string in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a school assignment and I can't manage to figure out. I've tried several different approaches to this including searching from the left, inside to out, and this is outside to in. I searched for over an hour online and on S.O.

I'm very new to programming so perhaps I just don't know what to look for or maybe this is too advanced for me just yet. I feel like I am missing something in my logic itself. If anyone can explain the logic, I would appreciate the patience.

Note: I have permission from my teacher to use Stack Overflow. If I'm doing this wrong here, please correct me and teach me how to make better posts- thank you.

The GOAL is to remove pairs of brackets. For instance:
This:

```
hello [ [ ] hello ] hello [ hello ] hello hello
```

Should result in this:

```
hello hello hello hello hello hello
```

And This:

```
] hello world ] ] [ HELLO ] WORLD ] ] ] hello world
```

Should result in this:

```
hello world ] ] HELLO ] WORLD ] ] ] hello world
```

This is my code:

```
    public class PairRemoval {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String text = "] hello world ] ] [ HELLO ] WORLD ] ] ] hello world";
            String leftPattern = "[";
            String rightPattern = "]";
    
            String sentence = pairRemoval(text, leftPattern, rightPattern);
    
            System.out.println(sentence);

            // Expected:  hello world ] ] HELLO ] WORLD ] ] ] hello world (per assignment)
            // Output:  ] hello world ] ] HELLO ] WORLD ] ] ] hello world

        }
        
        public static String pairRemoval(String text, String leftPattern, String rightPattern) {
    
            int count = 0;
            String sentence = "";
            int leftIndex = 0; // Initialize left index to search from the beginning of the string
            int rightIndex = text.length() - 1; // Initialize right index to search from the end of the string
        
            // Loop until the left and right indexes meet or cross each other
            while (leftIndex <= rightIndex) {
                char leftLetter = text.charAt(leftIndex);
                char rightLetter = text.charAt(rightIndex);
        
                // If the left letter matches the left pattern
                if (leftLetter == leftPattern.charAt(0)) {
                    count++;
                    leftIndex++;
                    continue; // Skip to next iteration to keep searching from the left
                }
        
                // If the right letter matches the right pattern
                if (rightLetter == rightPattern.charAt(0)) {
                    if (count > 0) {
                        count--;
                        rightIndex--;
                        continue; // Skip to next iteration to keep searching from the right
                    }
                }
        
                // If neither letter matches a pattern, append the left letter to the sentence
                sentence = sentence + leftLetter;
                leftIndex++;
               
            }
        
            // Return the final sentence with all pairs removed
            return sentence;
        }
```

Edit: Added example input output

```
text = 'hello [ [ ] hello ] hello [ hello ] hello hello'
left pattern = '['
right pattern = ']'
Expected value was: 'hello hello hello hello hello hello'

text = '> hello hello > > < hello > hello > > > hello hello'
left pattern = '<'
right pattern = '>'
Expected value was: ' hello hello > > hello > hello > > > hello hello'

text = '< < hello > hello hello hello > < hello < hello < > hello'
left pattern = '<'
right pattern = '>'
Expected value was: ' hello hello hello hello hello < hello < hello'

text = '[ [ [ hello [ [ hello hello hello hello [ [ ] ] hello hello'
left pattern = '['
right pattern = ']'
Expected value was: ' [ hello [ [ hello hello hello hello [ [ hello hello'

Example 1: 
text = { { hello } } { } hello hello } hello hello hello hello 
leftPattern =  {
rightPattern = }
expected = hello     hello hello } hello hello hello hello

Example 2: 
text = hello ( hello hello hello ) hello ) ) ) hello
leftPattern =  (
rightPattern = )
expected =. hello  hello hello hello  hello ) ) ) hello

Example 3: 
text = hello hello } { hello { } hello } { { hello
leftPattern =  {
rightPattern = }
expected = hello hello   hello   hello   { hello
```

Comment: First start with a very simple string, maybe `[ x ]` and step through your code with the debugger seeing how it works.

Comment: Also are you sure that you want to remove matched "reversed" brackets, i.e. `] x [` -> ` x `, which your second example implies?

Comment: I think the instructions are vague so I've been trying to figure out what's actually going on by looking at the testing and expected results. I edited and included the testing (replaces words with hello- it doesn't matter) It's interesting you say that, because I'm wondering if my big problem is that it's looking for both reversed and direct? I'm not actually sure. I've not yet fully developed the programming logic fully. I'm still learning and still somewhat very lost just following along with lessons still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by counting the number of each type of brackets in the string and iterate over the string by removing common number of pairs.

The algorithm:

```
str = "hello [ [ ] hello ] hello [ hello ] hello"

lcount = str.count('[')
rcount = str.count(']')

minimum = min(lcount, rcount) //Gives the number of pairs

lcount = minimum //Number of left brackets to be removed
rcount = minimum //Number of right brackets to be removed

for i in str:
    if (str[i] == '[' && lcount != 0):
        remove str[i];
        lcount--;
    else if (str[i] == ']' && rcount != 0):
        remove str[i];
        rcount--;
```

The java implementation:

```java
import static java.lang.Math.min;

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "] hello world ] ] [ HELLO ] WORLD ] ] ] hello world";
        String newStr = "";

        int lcount = str.length() - str.replace("[", "").length();
        int rcount = str.length() - str.replace("]", "").length();
        
        lcount = rcount = min(lcount, rcount);

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == '[' && lcount != 0) {
                lcount--;
            }
            else if (str.charAt(i) == ']' && rcount != 0){
                rcount--;
            }
            else{
                newStr += str.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(newStr);
    }
}
```

Output:

`hello world ] ]  HELLO ] WORLD ] ] ] hello world`

Comment: This fixed it! I put in char left = leftPattern.charAt(0); char right = rightPattern.charAt(0); and took out the hardcoded brackets and replaced it with the arguments so it can be used with any char. Including as note to future readers. It passed all the tests.